# RegEx to find TEXT plus up to 6 numbers

Tags: regex

[Using Notepad **]

Seeking a RegEx to find all of the following lines that contains the word "SEQ", a space, and then anywhere from 3 to 6 digits:

```
SEQ 123
SEQ 1234
SEQ 12345
SEQ 123456
```

I've tried a pattern like:

```
SEQ \d\d\d
```

..but I will miss out on digits containing the 4,5,6 placeholder.

Moreover,  I need to also *not* include any whitespace in that 3-6 character search. Sometimes a line looks like this:

```
SEQ 456 13
```

I wouldn't want to select any numbers beyond the number "6", in this case. I tried the following after looking at the RegEx Tutorial link:

```
SEQ \d{3,6}/\s/g
```

...but that errors out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what context you will use this in. There re many different regex languages and the details depend on what you are using. If you know the regex flavor, tell us that but if you don't, then tell us what tool you will use the regex in.

Comment: What do you want to do with strings that conain more than 6 digits like: `SEQ 123456789 13`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SEQ\s\d{3,6}`

The `{ }` is a regex [quantifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#quantifiers) that says:

Match the previous element `\d` at least 3x, but no more than 6x.

Check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) as well; it offers a lot of useful information and the ability to test regex patterns against strings.  [This](https://regex101.com/r/ssUb9j/1) shows your specific regex pattern.

Comment: Note that this assumes PCRE, not all regex flavors support `\d` or `{x,y}`.

Comment: @terdon is 100% correct!  I assumed and shouldn't have.  What language are you working with?  Can you also update your question with all possible cases that you're trying to find a regex for?

Comment: @JeffTaylor, `SEQ 456 13` wouldn't match "_the word "SEQ" plus anywhere from 3 to 6 digits_". If you want whitespace in the pattern you need to say to

Comment: @terdon I'm not using PCRE. I am using Notepad ++, so whatever RegEx that supports. \d and {x,y} work fine with it.

Comment: @Paulπ Question updated

Comment: @ChrisDavies question updated

Comment: @JeffTaylor, "_I'm not using PCRE. I am using Notepad ++_" - yes, you are [using PCRE](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/post/20900) (through Boost)

Comment: @ChrisDavies thanks for clarifying that for me.